# Filters on existing index

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a homework assignment where I have a nonclustered index. Later on in the assignment, I have to add a filter to the index. Is it possible to add a filter to an existing index?

This is my assignment and the order I have to do them in. In the end they all have to run as a single script.

1. Create an index following naming conventions on the transaction type column. It is used in ascending order.
2. Alter the index to have a fill factor of 80. We opt for not keeping the index online, we want full optimization.
3. We are actually only looking at transactions of type 'W', add a filter to the index.
4. Drop the index

For #3 do I have to drop the index I created in #1 add a new one with a filter and then drop it again in #4?

Comment: You cannot **add** a filter expression to an existing index - if you really need to "convert" a nonclustered index into a filtered index, you must drop it and re-create it with the filter expression.

Answer (score 1):

> For #3 do I have to drop the index I created in #1 add a new one with
>   a filter and then drop it again in #4?

SQL Server allows one to recreate an existing index using the syntax [CREATE INDEX...WITH(DROP EXISTING=ON)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql). This method avoids the need to drop the existing index beforehand and improves performance of the index recreate by leveraging the sort order of the original index. The `WITH` clause also provides additional options to meet your online requirement. See the documentation link above for details.

Comment: Thank you Dan, this is very helpful, so would my code look like this:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_TransactionType
ON PRODUCTION.TransactionHistory (TransactionType ASC)
WHERE TransactionType = 'W'
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);

Comment: @Gina, yes, you've found the answer for r homework ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can drop and create the same index again with added filter options in the Index. [Click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) this for more details.